# Fetching second level model with rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have  a  relationship in  which  a  post belongs to the  city which inturn belongs  to  a  state like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Now i  want to find all the  posts  along  with the their cities  and  the  states to which the  belong  to. I wrote the  following query to fetch the posts with their cities but out of ideas on how to fetch the  corresponding state with the  city in the same finder:

@post = Post.find :all, :include => [:city]

Any help is  appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Post.all( :include => { :city => :state })
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails will handle this for you, thanks to the [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) relation this information is fetched automatically.

```
@posts = Post.find(:all)
```

`@posts` now contains *the logic* to fetch the `city` and `city.state` details for all the returns posts.

If you are planning to *use all these details* you should eager load them, with `:include => { :city => :state }` as [Farrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109594/fetching-second-level-model-with-rails-active-record/2110221#2110221) and mckeed stated.

**Note:** to make it work the other way around (and it is also supposed good Model defining behaviour) you should add the `has_many` or `has_one` association as well. See the [Association Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: As your link explains, if you are going to access all the associated records, you should eager-load them with `:include` like in Farrel's answer. Otherwise when you loop through `@posts`, every time you ask for the post's city or state, it will do another database fetch, leading to much slower code.

Comment: You are completely right, thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer with this information.